# Issue during connect to Data Base using psql command

Tags: postgresql, centos, psql

I am using CentOS 6.3 and installed PostgreSQL 9.1 server. I'm connected to Postgres server using `psql` command:

```bash
psql -h localhost -U postgres
```

This is the result I got.

```
postgres=# \c MYDB  
psql (8.4.11, server 9.1.7)  
WARNING: psql version 8.4, server version 9.1.  
         Some psql features might not work.  
You are now connected to database "MYDB".  
MYDB=#
```

Can anyone please suggest me what could be the reason.

**Update**

Even when I uninstalled PostgreSQL 9.1 server, I still see the result for below commands.

```
[root@testserver bin]# find / -name 'postgres'
/var/spool/mail/postgres
[root@testserver bin]# find / -name 'psql'
/usr/bin/psql
[root@testserver bin]# which psql
/usr/bin/psql
[root@testserver bin]# which postgres
/usr/bin/which: no postgres in (/usr/lib64/qt-    3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/root/bin)
[root@testserver bin]# psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 8.4.11
contains support for command-line editing
[root@testserver bin]#
```

Here my intention is, if you execute `which psql` command, it should not display any output if server is not installed. I uninstalled Postgres server and removed `/opt/PostgreSQL` folder too but I still see it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are using `psql` version 8.4 to connect to a 9.1 database.

Presumably the default `psql` on the `PATH` is the old version.

If you installed 9.1 using `yum.postgresql.org` you should look at the output of:

```
update-alternatives --display pgsql-psql
```

as most likely you have both 9.1 and 8.4 installed, and the older one is set as default. If so, run:

```
update-alternatives --auto pgsql-psql
```

to choose the newer version automatically, or:

```
update-alternatives --config pgsql-psql
```

to manually select which to run.

If you installed 9.1 by some other means, you'll need to use a full explicit `/path/to/9.1/bin/psql` (whever your 9.1 install is), or change your `PATH` to point to that `bin` dir before the system default ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Craig, small doube that is there any default psql client as part of CentOS install.

Comment: What's the output of `which psql` and `rpm -qif psql` and `update-alternatives --display pgsql-psql`? And how did you install PostgreSQL, from where, using what repository/packages/installer?

Comment: which psql=/usr/bin/psql, for rest of two commands didn't show anything.As part of some other application am installing this postgres too in unattended mode.postgresql-9.1.7-1-linux-x64.run is the one I used to install the Postgres.

Comment: @Honey  ... and you downloaded that installer from ...? As for the other commands, try `ls -al /usr/bin/psql` instead, then. Anyway, since you've installed some 3rd party package you need to update your PATH to use their psql or use an explicit path like `/opt/postgresql91/bin/psql` or wherever it installed to.